# CircleCI build FAILURE on Android support libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, continuous-integration, circleci

Experimenting today... Local project runs fine, CircleCI output below. [See my circle.yml here](https://gist.github.com/es0329/e1bb497e4db243ea0e6f815debffe029).

```
> Configuring > 2/2 projectsFAILURE: 
> Configuring > 2/2 projectsBuild failed with an exception.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects
> Configuring > 2/2 projects
> Configuring > 2/2 projects* What went wrong:
> Configuring > 2/2 projectsA problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> 
> Configuring > 2/2 projectsCould not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects   
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> 
> Configuring > 2/2 projectsCould not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects     Searched in the following locations:
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.jar
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.jar
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.jar
> Configuring > 2/2 projects     Required by:
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         Fool-Android:app:unspecified
> Configuring > 2/2 projects   
> Configuring > 2/2 projects> 
> Configuring > 2/2 projectsCould not find com.android.support:design:23.3.0.
> Configuring > 2/2 projects     Searched in the following locations:
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.3.0/design-23.3.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.3.0/design-23.3.0.jar
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.3.0/design-23.3.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.3.0/design-23.3.0.jar
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.3.0/design-23.3.0.pom
> Configuring > 2/2 projects         file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.3.0/design-23.3.0.jar
```

Comment: Circle can't find Android's appcompat and design support libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by moving support libs to the end of build config file... seems ordering was the difference. See revised Gist.